# Usage of Papaparse with Angular 2: Cannot find name 'Papa'

Tags: angular, typescript, papaparse

I am working on a project where I upload a csv file and parse it to view the results in a list. Everything worked fine untill I deleted my node_modules to re-install them to get rid other errors. When I did npm updated my node modules again the definition of 'Papa' can not be found again and I don't know how to let Angular 2 find the name 'Papa' so that my application works again.

I tried adding `import {} from '../../papaparse.min.js'` to reference to the location of the papaparse file but this didn't work.

Is there a certain module I need to add in my app.module again? I used the `npm install papaparse` command to install papaparse.

Comment: I would recommend using https://github.com/Alberthaff/ngx-papaparse, it makes it strait forward to work with PapaParse and Angular. For Angular 2 just install it with `npm install ngx-papaparse@1.2.5 --save`

Comment: thanks! This is indeed more pleasant to use. I only have one problem left. In the console I see this error: `node_modules\@types\papaparse\index.d.ts:19:31 
    Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.` is there another package to add?

Comment: nevermind, solved it bij deleting the @types/papaparse :) guess it was an old package just sitting there.

Comment: Great, I'll create an answer for you to close this question then.

Comment: could some one post complete example with view ? am not event able to how to start... :(

Comment: @Idiot_cheg have you checked of the docs? It looks like the examples are pretty complete https://github.com/Alberthaff/ngx-papaparse/wiki/Parsing-CSV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using github.com/Alberthaff/ngx-papaparse, it makes it strait forward to work with PapaParse and Angular. For Angular 2 just install it with `npm install ngx-papaparse@1.2.5 --save`